# Google Play Console: Replace an app with another with same package name and signing key

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I want to redo my old Android app with better code and UX, it's easier and faster than edit the old one, my question is, if I use the same package name and signing key for the new app and incrementing the version code as needed, it's going to be possible to upload the new Bundle and replace the old app with the new one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be. As long as your package name is same its not going to give you any trouble. You can try first releasing to internal testing track and see how is that working for you before rolling out in production.